# Why doesn't adding sqrt() cause a conflict in C++?

Tags: c++

If I write a new function that has the signature of a C library function, I expect a compile error due to the ambiguity. But, I can't understand why there is no error in the following C++ code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double sqrt(double number)
{
    return number * 2;  
}

int main( )
{
    cout << sqrt(2.3) << endl;
    cout << ::sqrt(2.3) << endl;
    cout << std::sqrt(2.3) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If I change the return type of sqrt() to int, then a compile error occurs due to the declaration ambiguity with double sqrt() in cmath. How is it possible to override double sqrt()? (Actually, all the cmath functions can be overridden, and I don't know why.)

Comment: Maybe works because you declare your own function in a way that is compatible with the global declaration? ***Or*** (and much more likely) it differs enough to create a brand new overload?

Comment: What is really driving my crazy is `std::sqrt(2.3)` is calling your function as well.  Why do you do this to me C++???

Comment: @NathanOliver It's not really C++ doing this to you. It's C. See that `c` letter in `#include <cmath>`?

Comment: @n.m. But it's C++ fault for inheriting from C ;)

Comment: Function argument types are part of the functions' signature, *the return type is not*. As such, defining `int sqrt(double)` has the same signature as the declaration within the standard header, but conflicts with it due to the return type. On the other hand, `double sqrt(int)` would pass without complaint because: The signature is different from the declaration within the header, so it simply adds an overload for integer arguments.

Comment: @NathanOliver Well, n.m.'s answer points out that this is UB, so the compiler is allowed to do bullshit with `std::sqrt()`... I guess that's because `std::sqrt()` is nothing but a namespace wrapper for the C function `sqrt()` which has `extern "C"` linkage.

Comment: Do not try to reason or rationalize an undefined behavior .

Comment: Also, do not taunt Happy Fun Ball.

Comment: @NathanOliver The names in cmath will be in both global and std namespace. I wanted to show that my new sqrt() replaces the cmath sqrt() in both namespaces.

Comment: @NathanOliver C++ only has that much manpower. Either inheritit from C this way, or don't have it at all. A no-brainer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The program has undefined behaviour.

> [reserved.names]
>   1 The C++ standard library reserves the following kinds of names:
>   1.1) — macros
>   1.2) — global names
>   1.3) — names with external linkage
>   2 If a program declares or defines a name in a context where it is reserved, other than as explicitly allowed by this Clause, its behavior is undefined.
>
> [extern.names]
>   4 Each function signature from the C standard library declared with external linkage is reserved to the
>   implementation for use as a function signature with both extern "C" and extern "C++" linkage, or as a
>   name of namespace scope in the global namespace.

Comment: It is mostly the equivalent of ODR violation of standard functions.

Comment: The above code doesn't try to declare a function in a context where it is reserved, i.e. does not try to declare it IN the std namespace. I would say in the context of this program, the declaration is just hiding the std one. However, this view does not explain @NathanOliver point about explicitly writing std::sqrt

Comment: @WilliamClements this name is reserved as a global name, not only in std namespace.

Comment: @n.m. Why do you think only double sqrt() shows the UB, while int sqrt() doesn't? (int sqrt gives a compile error.)

Comment: @WilliamClements Well, it does declare `sqrt()` within the global namespace, for which that name is reserved as the last paragraph of the cited text indicates. Ergo, UB.

Comment: @austin Both have UB. In one case you get a compiler warning, in the other unexpected behavior. Both are valid implementations of UB. What you get is entirely down to the whims of the compiler.

Comment: @austin It's a logical fallacy. You cannot deduce that a program has no UB by observing its behaviour and noticing that it does what you expect it to do.